# PHP - Restart insertion with (#) rows (where the user selects a # from a dropdown list)

Tags: php

I would like to add a feature to my website that I have seen within phpMyAdmin. The feature can be seen on phpMyAdmin's Insert tab: at the very bottom of the Insert tab page, there is a line that says, "Restart insertion with (#) rows". Below is the selection source. I would like to add a similar dropdown list to my page that has a single group of inputs.

For example, when a user selects "Restart insertion with 15 rows", the page will render 15 groups of inputs to be filled out. How could I do this within my PHP/mySQL page? Could someone provide a working sample that changes the number of groups of inputs based upon the number selected from the dropdown list? I am hoping to accomplish this without Javascript or Jquery.

```
<form method="post" action="tbl_replace.php" name="restartForm">
<input name="db" value="databasename" type="hidden">
<input name="table" value="MyTable" type="hidden">
<input name="token" value="somerandomnumber" type="hidden">
<input name="goto" value="tbl_structure.php" type="hidden">
<input name="err_url" value="tbl_structure.php?goto=tbl_structure.php&amp;amp;db=databasename&amp;amp;table=MyTable&amp;amp;server=1&amp;amp;token=somerandomnumber" type="hidden">
<input name="sql_query" value="" type="hidden">

Restart insertion with <select name="insert_rows" id="insert_rows" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="40" selected="selected">40</option>
</select>
 rows<noscript><input type="submit" value="Go" /></noscript>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is OpenSource. You can just read the code or even copy it, if you also publish your code under the same license. And yes, at least the old versions where done without much JavaScript.